# Q: Generate argument list at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, tuples, metaprogramming

I'm trying to create some tuple at compile time, just a type and a bitset (which represent the type for some operations).

I want something like:

```
<Foo1,0x001>, <Foo2,0x002>, <Foo3,0x003>...
```

That's why I have a Metadata struct:

```
template < typename T,
           size_t Size >
struct Metadata {

  using type = T;

  std::bitset<Size>  bitset;
};
```

And, thanks to everyone, the make function is something like that:

```
template <typename...Ts,typename...Args>
constexpr auto make_metadata(Args... args)
{
    constexpr auto N = sizeof...(Ts);
    return std::make_tuple(Metadata<Ts, N>{args}...);
}
```

But I need to give it the bitset value right now. And I know the bitset value at compile time as I said at the beginning. So **how could I generate an argument list like (0,1,2,...,N - 1) ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With C++14, you can use [`std::integer_sequence` and `std::make_integer_sequence()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to generate a compile-time parameter pack of monotonically increasing integers, which should work in your use case.